# why salesforce allow us to deploy class with 0 percent code coverage

Tags: code-coverage

I understand that test class's purposes is to develop as-much-as-possible robust & error-free code and we need at least 75% code coverage overall to deploy the class in production. But its hard to understand why salesforce allow us to deploy the class with 0% code coverage. Why aren't we forced to cover the classs to check if its robust and error free before being deployed to Production?

Comment: In what scenario can you deploy a class with 0 code coverage?

Comment: When the overall coverage is more than 75%. Basically as a best practice , i never deploy a class with proper coverage but just wanted to know why we can deploy class with 0% coverage and trigger with 1% coverage.

Comment: good question! I guess there might be cases where a class only contains code, that is not testable.

Comment: @basti Thats seems logical. But i am wondering what could be those senarios where in the code cannnot be covered?

Comment: We are having parts in our product, where we need to mock currencies in test's because you can't change currencies programmatically. So the code where we use original currencies is never touched. This is just a small example and we are not having this in an extra class, but you could possibly write it like that. Same might apply for other things you mock.

Comment: I did some googling but could not find such class where in i can not cover any code coverage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very interesting finding on this, from Jeff Douglas' [blog](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/03/04/how-to-deploy-apex-without-test-coverage/), where Salesforce product manager is being quoted as follows

> Code coverage is measured across all of your apex classes and
>   triggers. Triggers are the only logical blocks that specifically
>   **require >0%** coverage because we know they are in use. The same can not
>   be said for classes **so there is no class-level coverage requirement in
>   place at this time.** When you deploy your code using eclipse the
>   existing tests are run and if the coverage is sufficient your
>   deployment will succeed. I presume you had code deployed already and
>   that the additional (untested) controller code you deployed did not
>   drop your overall coverage below the minimum level.  If you do a
>   global run all tests you should still find yourself above the minimum.

From the above we can conclude that

- in any deployment, **trigger code** coverage should be >0 even if entire organization's code coverage is >75%.

  - although, trigger code coverage requirement >0%, but it is the lines of code that count in the entire org's code coverage. So, if the trigger **1%** coverage but has as many lines of code as to make the org coverage **drop** below 75%, then the trigger won't be deployed. and you will need to either cover more lines of your trigger or make your org coverage higher so deploying the trigger won't drop it below 75%.
- class code coverage is not a requirement as long as the org entire coverage is >75%, after deployment of that class.

**P.S.** This article was written in 2009, since [winter '16](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_deployment_change_sets_test_levels.htm), salesforce has introduced number of methods to deploy apex via changesets by running tests with different options, therefore the article is talking about eclipse but it is true for inbound changesets as well.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot Mahmood

Answer (score 2):

It is just 75% total code coverage across your entire organization:

> - At least 75% of your Apex code must be covered by unit tests, and all    of those tests must complete successfully. **Note the
>     following:**
> - When deploying to a production organization, every unit test in your organization namespace is executed.
> - Calls to System.debug are not counted as part of Apex code coverage.
> - Test methods and test classes are not counted as part of Apex code coverage.
> - While only 75% of your Apex code must be covered by tests, your focus shouldn't be on the percentage of code that is covered. Instead,
>     you should make sure that every use case of your application is
>     covered, including positive and negative cases, as well as bulk and
>     single records. This should lead to 75% or more of your code being
>     covered by unit tests.
> - Every trigger must have some test coverage.
> - All classes and triggers must compile successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Suraj but  i wanted to understand why we can deploy with 0% code coverage.

Comment: In short, in order to deploy, each class that you are trying to deploy needs to have >75% coverage in order to deploy. So if you have a class in your sandbox org with 50% code coverage, then you are not going to be able to deploy to production." You can deploy classes with 0% code coverage as long as the average across the board is 75% or more. You could also just not include them in the deploy.

Comment: I will be able to deploy the class with <50 as well or even 0 when the overall is >75

Comment: Yup, You can because it take overall.

Comment: I don’t know if a scenario where a class would have to have 0% coverage. At least not one in use